# Django : fullcalendar, each event with a different color

Tags: django, events, fullcalendar, background-color

How to associate each event with a different color for the background ?

I recorded a number of events with the administration interface

my function (view module) returns records with json.dumps(event_list)
and I have for the visualiation file

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today, save',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,agendaFourDay'
        },

                   'defaultView': 'month',
        editable: true,



               views: {
    agendaFourDay: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { days: 4 },
        buttonText: '4 day'
    }
},

        events: '/events_json/',



        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            document.location.href = '/admin/notes/event/'+ calEvent.id + '/';
        },
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            document.location.href = '/admin/notes/event/add/';
        },



                                                      },


    });

});
```

I tried to add :

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) 
  {
          var date = new Date(); 

            if (event.start >= date) {
                 element.css('background-color', '#000');
                                     }

 }
```

but element.css don't work...

my model is :

```
class Event(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(_('titre'), max_length=100)
start = models.DateTimeField(_('debut'))
end = models.DateTimeField(_('fin'))
is_cancelled = models.BooleanField(_('Annulation?'), default=False, blank=True)
calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, verbose_name=_('categorie'))
user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, blank= True, null = True, verbose_name=_('utilisateur'))
description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
frequency = models.CharField(_(u"Occurence(s) :"), choices=freqs, max_length=10, default=0)
fin = models.IntegerField(_(u"Fin après un nombre d'occurence(s) de  :"), choices=CYCLES, default=0)
rep = models.IntegerField(_(u"décalage (jours) de  :"), choices=DELAY, default=0)
activated = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Activation ?', default=False, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title
```

I read all events with  events: '/events_json/'

if I put in the javascript file :

```
 var date = new Date(); 

        if (event.start <= date) {
            document.write(event);
```

I have : [object Object][object Object]

maybe, It is the problem with element.css('background-color', '#000');

what to do ?

Comment: I tried changing the bgcolor as you given above and it worked.

Comment: I meant the background-color only. eventRender: function(event, element, view) { if(event.start >= new Date(2015,1,1)) {     element.css('background-color', '#000'); } } For me this code part worked correctly

Comment: for me, your code don't work. It is a problem...